# ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-01031

I'm facing the below error while trying to login to database. Oracle services were up and running but was not able to login.

Error:ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

I tried to do the below. But i don't have sufficient privileges to run.Kindly suggest

Enter user-name: / as sysdba

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: This question is a better fit on: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sai I am afraid without administrator level logon privilege, you cannot startup the database.